# How to return INDEX MATCH Function from result cell or ABOVE if its blank

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Im using INDEX MATCH function to search and return the result; however, the result cell can be empty. So if the result cell is empty, I want the formula to return the data from the cell above (can be from few rows above).

After researching, seems like I have to use ISBLANK, but I'm stuck on the formula.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Iwan

Comment: Welcome! @Iwan Radius. Please provide the formula you currently have, the result you are getting from it and the result you expect based on data that you are also sharing in the question. I am guessing this is Excel but it's nice to give people you want help from more context so they don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX($C$4:$C$10,MATCH(I8,$D$4:$D$10,0))),K7,INDEX($C$4:$C$10,MATCH(I8,$D$4:$D$10,0)))
```

I attach a screenshot so that you can see the example that you shared in a picture, solved.

[image]